# GCM Config file and account required to create it

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

Have a question regaring GCM and the google-services.json file creation. When you go to the website trying to create this file, you need to crete or specify a project. I can't find anywhere if this project must be created from the Google account used to publish the application in Google Play or any Google account would do.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

**Updatate:**
All accounts used are developer accounts. Just want to understand if it is a requirement to use the same Google account for the app in Google Play.

Comment: I think you need the developer account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have already added the project to your google publication list then it should be in the pull down list. if not then you need to create it from the dash board [here](https://console.developers.google.com/)

you will need to have a paid developer account to do this. Which ever account you are logged in as needs to have the project in the dash board otherwise you wont get access to it